# URL array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm using codeigniter (newbie at codeigniter).

I have a function `getproducts($p1, $p2, $p3)` in a controller.

When I call `getproducts/0/0/` from my jquery-script (ajax) it works, **but I want to call URL like this**:

```
getproducts/0/0/{"0":"13","1":"24"}
```

it doesn't work. (I get into to google-search-results instead of staying at my local webserver)

I basically want to pass an array to a function in the url somehow when using codeigniter. How should I solve that? Please help :-)

Comment: I think you need to use `JSON` in this kind of stuff, Since a `Javascript array` is different with `PHP array`

Comment: How exactly do you mean? Is the JSON-format incorrect?

Comment: this is a GET request. But what you are asking to do is more suited to a POST request because you can more easily pass your JSON object using POST

Comment: Juventus18, make your comment an answer! So I can accept.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should at least adjust the Codeigniter's config about allowed characters in the URL to include curly braces, comma and double quotes :

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = ',{}"a-z 0-9~%.:_()@\-';
```

The reason why you end up on Google might however be something else (does not seem to be Codeigniter related)

Answer (score 1):

Your browser don't think that that is a URL and navigates to google (thinking that you are searching something), I Think.

The main parts of URLs

A full BNF description of the URL syntax is given in Section 5.

In general, URLs are written as follows:

```
   <scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>
```

A URL contains the name of the scheme being used () followed
   by a colon and then a string (the ) whose
   interpretation depends on the scheme.

Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters. The lower case
   letters "a"--"z", digits, and the characters plus ("+"), period
   ("."), and hyphen ("-") are allowed. For resiliency, programs
   interpreting URLs should treat upper case letters as equivalent to
   lower case in scheme names (e.g., allow "HTTP" as well as "http").

Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
   reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
   unencoded within a URL.

```
schemepart     = *xchar | ip-schemepart
```

See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html please.

Answer (score 1):

{"0":"13","1":"24"} should be url encoded.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

I think a better answer for this question would be to use the inbuilt uri to associative array handler.  see http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html?highlight=uri 
this stops all that nasty mucking about with config permitted uri characters.

your uri would be: getproducts/p1/0/p2/0/p3/0/p5/13/p6/1/p6/24
and the handler would be something like:

```
 function get_product()
 {
      $object = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [URI class's](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)
`$this->uri->assoc_to_uri()`

Manual wrote,

> Takes an associative array as input and generates a URI string from it. 
>   The array keys will be included in the string. Example:

```
$array = array('product' => 'shoes', 'size' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
$str = $this->uri->assoc_to_uri($array);
// Produces: product/shoes/size/large/color/red
```

Comment: I don't want to generate an url. The url is created client-side (jQuery).