# How to allow double quotes (quoation marks) in CodeIgniter URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

New to CodeIgniter but I've tried a few approaches:

[Remove Characters from URL with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818776/remove-characters-from-url-with-htaccess) / 
[URL array codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015096/url-array-codeigniter) / 
[CodeIgniter Disallowed Key Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)

I keep getting the same error when a URL that contains a double quote is used:

```
Disallowed Key Characters.
```

Please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. This seemed so simple at first but clearly I'm not understanding.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It is a security hole. Anyway urlencode may come handy:

http://www.php.net/urlencode

Comment: It's an ecommerce site with a lot of traffic and one of its traffic sources - Google Shopping - is sending a long string of variables attached to our traditional URLs which I'm assuming is some form of analytics tracking set up by a previous developer.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the config folder in your CI directory look for the line:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

If you want to use double quotes add it there.

Next go to **codeigniter->core->input.php**

find the : `_clean_input_keys($str) function`

append this line: `exit('Disallowed Key Characters.'.$str);`

Now you should see the line that's causing your error and fix it accordingly.

Comment: I think better to extend input class with /application/code/MY_Input.php than edit CI core

Comment: I was unable to get the above to resolve my issue but thank you still Edward.

Answer (score 0):

This is what seemed to work for me. I realize after consulting several sources there are various ways to resolve this issue. I modified this section inside of html/system/core/Input.php to match the following. I inserted a PHP function that that replaces instances of " with ' for the URL strings. Did the job.

```
 /**
  * Clean Keys
  *
  * This is a helper function. To prevent malicious users
  * from trying to exploit keys we make sure that keys are
  * only named with alpha-numeric text and a few other items.
  *
  * @access private
  * @param  string
  * @return string
  */
  function _clean_input_keys($str)
  {
     $str = str_replace('"','',$str);
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
    {
      exit('Disallowed Key Characters...');
    }

    // Clean UTF-8 if supported
    if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
    {
      $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
    }

    return $str;
  }
```